# Retrieving value of treemap does not retrieve object name

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have a TreeMap, I assign Integer as key and Student as its value. Is there a way to print the Student types exact name?

For example, in the driver class I will instantiate student as:

```
    Student two   = new Student(1002,"two"  );
```

Is there a way for the get() function or the pollFirstEntry() to return the actual name of the instantiated student object, i.e. "two"? Instead of Student@XXXXXXXXX.

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

public  class Table <K extends Comparable<K>, T>  // K = key,  T = item
{
    TreeMap<K,T> tree      = new TreeMap<K,T>();
    TreeMap<K,T> treeclone = new TreeMap<K,T>();

  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    if (tree.size()>0)                      
        return false;
    return true;
  }

   public int size()
   {
       return tree.size();   
   }

   public T tableRetrieve(K key)
   {
       return tree.get(key);
   }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void printTable()
   {
       treeclone = (TreeMap<K, T>)tree.clone();   
       int n = treeclone.size();
       for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
       {
          System.out.println(treeclone.pollFirstEntry());
       }
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT USING RETRIEVE FUNCTION**

```
1003: Student@22b3ea59
```

**OUTPUT USING PRINTTABLE FUNCTION**

```
1002=Student@4903f4aa
1003=Student@22b3ea59
1004=Student@13ce168b
1005=Student@3f2a09d5
1006=Student@60eb9f58
1007=Student@d2a7c1e
1008=Student@603a9c52
1009=Student@27ecfcd9
1010=Student@37cc1f09
```

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` method in your `Student` class. `toString()`s default implementation is determined by [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) which prints what you are currently seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the toString() function for printing.
For the get function you get back an item of type T, if T has a toString() method defined for itself then you can do the following to return a printable string.

```
return tree.get(key).toString();
```

For an arbitrary object of type T you will need to override the toString() method to provide an implementation.

Comment: When you print an Object, `toString()` is already called implicitly.